# Use of DominoTree model in saxon xquery processing

Tags: xquery, saxon

I am trying to leverage the new DominoTree model to replace the use of Document model for executing xqueries in our code, that uses saxon 10 for xquery processing. I wanted to know if there is anything saxon supports out of the box, like a configuration setting, to enable saxon to internally use domino tree model.
eg

```
EnterpriseConfiguration pc = new EnterpriseConfiguration();
pc.setTreeModel(2);
```

Or are we supposed to do the conversion(dom to domino) in our code before sending it to saxon.
eg

```
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

DominoTree domTree = DominoTree.makeTree(doc, eeconfig, "systemID");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed construct the DominoTree explicitly as you suggested.

You can also select the DominoTreeModel as the default at various levels, but typically only in low-level classes like Controller and ParseOptions. This is deliberate, because there's no good use case for building a DominoTree directly from raw XML, it's only there for the case where your application has already constructed a DOM tree and you now want to process it using Saxon.

A raw DOM is about 5-10 times slower to process in Saxon than a TinyTree. Wrapping it in a DominoTree gives you an overhead (both space and time) to construct indexes, but after that the navigation overhead is a lot smaller, in fact many operations go as fast as the TinyTree.

Given the description of your project, I think my instinct would be to get rid of DOM entirely. If you need the tree to be mutable, go for JDOM2 or XOM; otherwise just use a Saxon TinyTree.

Comment: thanks Michael. The restriction we have currently is that, its a legacy code base, which has around 1 year of work needed to get rid of Document object - so we are trying to use Domino, while we work on moving to TinyTree. Could you elaborate a little on how to do "You can also select the DominoTreeModel as the default at various levels, but typically only in low-level classes like Controller and ParseOptions", as i tried to dig into the libraries but failed to find how to set it - i was only able to set the model to TINY_TREE, TINY_TREE_CONDENSED and LINKED_TREE.

Comment: `Controller` and `ParseOptions` both allow `setTreeModel(DominoTreeModel.getInstance()`. But you really don't want to set it on the `Controller` because then every temporary tree held in an xsl:variable would use this model. Setting it on `ParseOptions` is more reasonable - but not on the default `ParseOptions` used by everything.

Comment: Thanks for your help Michael, we are able to use Domino and see improvements. Do you have any recommendations for using Domino to run queries on parts of XML documents, ie Element objects? Issue is - DominoTree can be constructed only using a whole DOM - hence one way to use DominoTree, is to create a new Document(DOM) using a clone of the required Element and then create DominoTree using this new Document(DOM). However, this would increase memory consumption, hence we are looking for a way to create DominoTree without copying it to a new Document(DOM). Is there any way available to do that?

Comment: No, it has to be the whole document. You may be better off copying the DOM subtree to a TinyTree.

Comment: that would work, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: hi Michael, could you give some reference code for converting a Dom Element to tiny tree and vice versa? I have the following code, wanted to know if its the recommended way, or is there a better way: `final Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer();
   // set up holder for the output
   final TinyBuilder outputTarget = new TinyBuilder(
      pipeconfig);

   // transform into Saxon's immutable TinyTree
   transformer.transform(new DOMSource(firstItem), outputTarget);
   TinyTree tt = outputTarget.getTree();
   NodeInfo nodeInfo =  tt.getRootNode();`

Comment: I would do it using the s9api DocumentBuilder.build() - use setTreeModel() to define the target tree model, and choose a Source appropriate to the source tree model, e.g. a DOMSource. The JAXP identity transformer will work very similarly but probably has a bit more overhead using SAX rather than Saxon's internal Receiver interface.

Comment: yes i tried using that, but DocumentBuilder.build() looks to build a document - so the source thats supplied to it needs to be a Document - it wasnt working for an Element. Could you share sample code of how this can be used?

Comment: hi michael, could you help me with what Source to give, when generating tinyTree from a document element? using DOMSource and then doing DocumentBuilder builder = saxonProcessor.newDocumentBuilder(); builder.build() complains of the source not being a whole document.

Comment: You should be able to wrap a DOMSource around a DOM Element node.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, the Domino tree model in Saxon EE is not meant as a replacement for DOM, it is an intent to allow you to use DOM but speed up its use in Saxon, see https://www.saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!sourcedocs/domino.

So you can of course work with Saxon without the need for any DOM tree, just use what the DocumentBuilder gives you or look at the tiny or linked tree implementations, but if you have a need to use a DOM tree and happen to use Saxon EE then using Domino can speed up your queries in comparison to only using DOM.